# Visual Elements not updating in real time with Taipy GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, charts, taipy

Is it normal that when I attempt to add a value to my list or change my data using a button, I do not observe any modifications on the GUI?

Despite this, after refreshing the page, the accurate list is displayed.

```py
from taipy.gui import Gui
import pandas as pd

a_list = [1,2,3]
data = pd.DataFrame({"x":[1,2,3], "y":[2,1,3]})


md = """
<|Update|button|on_action=update|>

# My list
<|{a_list}|>

# My data
<|{data}|table|width=fit-content|>
"""

def update(state):
    state.a_list.append(4)
    state.data["y"] = [10, 4, 3] 

Gui(md).run()
```

For example, in the code above, clicking the button should add 4 to my list and change my table. However, I see no modification in real time. When I refresh my page, I see the right modifications.

### After clicking and before refreshing:

[image]

### After refreshing:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taipy does not directly change your GUI with this set of specific assignments (`.append()`, `.drop()`). You must use a regular ‘equals’ assignment to see changes in real time (`state.xxx = yyy`). Your code will look like this:

```
from taipy.gui import Gui
import pandas as pd

a_list = [1,2,3]
data = pd.DataFrame({"x":[1,2,3], "y":[2,1,3]})


md = """
<|Update|button|on_action=update|>

# My list
<|{a_list}|>

# My data
<|{data}|table|width=fit-content|>
"""

def update(state):
    state.a_list += [4]
    temp = state.data
    temp["y"] = [10, 4, 3] 
    state.data = temp

Gui(md).run()
```